# How do I set the exact post date timestamp as Views contextual filter?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I need to display nodes that were created within a certain period of time.

Setting `Date: Date (node) (content: post date)` as contextual Views filter works super smooth. Now when I call `archive/2014-04-01-10--2014-04-04-15` all nodes created between April 1st 10am and April 4th 3pm will be displayed.

But how can I set the granularity to also respect minutes (and seconds)? How to alter the date filter or how to write a custom timestamp contextual filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you only have to pass the hours and minutes in to your contextual filter.

I have a View with filtering between dates and the URL is like that:
http://mysite.com/myview?changed%5Bmin%5D=23-03-2013+12%3A24&changed%5Bmax%5D=23-03-2013+18%3A24

This is for the access data from 23-03-2013 12:24 to 23-03-2013 18:24.

Also, make sure you have enabled the Date submodule Date views as it provides some improvements using dates in Views.

Comment: Thanks! It simply works with a URL like `mysite.com/my-archive-view/2014-04-01+10:20:00--2014-04-07+09:23:00`

Comment: What about seconds? Is that possible?